# How to show comment reply form

Tags: forms, ajax, comments

I have installed [ajax comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) module. There is a "reply" link to show comment reply form. I want to show comment reply form under comments without click reply link. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

if (you = JS) {

use `document.getElementById('yourLinkID').click();`

} else if (you = JS && you = jQuery){

use `$('.content-type #LinkID').click();`

} else {

// can't think of anything, either then an option in the UI. I don't have much experience with Drupal comments.

}